# Servlet programming using eclipse ide with weblogic server

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I'm new to JavaEE and just started using eclipse with weblogic server,
whenever i try open localhost page in internal webbrowser, it gives Error 404, even i'm not able to execute hello world program in eclipse, please help me how to resolve this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if the web.xml file has the correct welcome tag and welcome pages.

Comment: post ur web.xml code here

Comment: verify your context root, try to add a simple html file (is it working?), if html file is working then something is not okay with your servlet config in web.xml (or if used servlet annotations). Give us more details pls

Comment: thanks for the suggestion friends, its working now,.. :)